# Simple macro parameter syntax in x86 Assembly, address calculation

Tags: assembly, syntax, parameters, x86, nasm

Not sure why I cannot use eax in the address calculation... the following return an invalid operand type error...

I have a macro that takes one parameter:

```
    %macro  IdPrompt 1      ; 1% - the offset within Buff at which to write the ID that is read in                                                                                                                             

    mov eax, 3              ; Specify sys_read call                                                                                                                                                                            
    mov ebx, 0              ; Specify File Descriptor 0: Stdin                                                                                                                                                                 
    mov ecx, Buff+([%1]*2)  ; Pass offset of the buffer to read ID into, 2 is the scale                                                                                                                                                        
    mov edx, 3              ; Pass number of bytes to read at one pass                                                                                                                                                         
    int 80h                 ; call sys_read to fill the buffer                                                                                                                                                                 
    %endmacro
```

The macro is called by this within another macro:

```
    IdPrompt eax            ; call IdPrompt to get one ID
```

I tried using a smaller register, as well as with the Buffer address as: Buff+%1*2 with no luck

Comment: Which assembler you are using?

Comment: How is it supposed to work? You're overwriting `eax` before referencing it. As you for the syntax I think `[Buff + %1 * 2]` might work in this case.

Comment: I did not realize that the parameters were just references to the registers... I'll just switch the order... and it looks like your suggestion worked, thank you

Comment: And what answer we have to vote up now?

Comment: I went with:   mov ecx, Buff ... and then ... lea ecx, [ecx+(%1*2)]

Answer (score 1):

As per @user786653's comment:

The correct syntax is:

```
%macro  IdPrompt 1      ; 1% - the offset within Buff at which to write the ID that is read in                                                                                                                             

mov eax, 3              ; Specify sys_read call                                                                                                                                                                            
mov ebx, 0              ; Specify File Descriptor 0: Stdin                                                                                                                                                                 
lea ecx, [Buff+%1*2]    ; Pass offset of the buffer to read ID into, 2 is the scale                                                                                                                                                        
mov edx, 3              ; Pass number of bytes to read at one pass                                                                                                                                                         
int 80h                 ; call sys_read to fill the buffer                                                                                                                                                                 
%endmacro
```

Note that `lea` never accesses memory; it only does address calculation.
So even though the argument is in `[]` square brackets, you're using the literal register values.

The `%1` gets replaced by a register reference.  In your example: `lea ecx,[eax*2+Buff]`